# How to get CustomerId in API in magento 2? and how magento gets customerId for the same?

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, customer-session

Magento didn't load the **customer session** in **API** as used in web session based authentications.

and i am aware about the API

```
<magento.host>/rest/V1/customers/me
```

> My question is, how do I make that call with **PHP**, so my code
>   captures the `customer ID` and can use it.
>
> How do I make a call to that URL programmatically and capture the
>   `User ID` into a **PHP** variable?
>
> **How magento make calls in-between for the APIs ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally got the solution, i am trying my best to explain it.

so here's how **Magento works** !!

Magento gets the customer data with passing anything except **token value** in **API** call.

In between magento calls some API related controllers for the same

> vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
 </route>
```

**in this API call magento get customer data based on token.**

Based on API url `url="/V1/customers/me"` magento calls function from

Magento calls In-between call of dispatch function.

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php

```
 public function dispatch(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
 {
     /** In between code **/
     // In the same file
     $this->processApiRequest();

 }
 protected function processApiRequest()
 {
      $inputParams = $this->getInputParamsResolver()->resolve();
 }
```

**And this `resolve()` function calls `override()` function**

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php

```
 public function resolve()
 {
      $inputData = $this->paramsOverrider->override($inputData, $route->getParameters());
 }
```

and `overide()` function calls `getOverriddenValue()` function

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamsOverrider.php

```
 public function override(array $inputData, array $parameters)
 {
      $value = $this->paramOverriders[$paramValue]->getOverriddenValue();
 }
```

`getOverriddenValue()` calls `ParamOverriderInterface`

> vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request/ParamOverriderInterface.php

- To Override parameter values
- Parameters in the webapi.xml can be forced. This ensures that on
  specific routes, a specific value is always used.
- For instance, if there is a `".../me/..."` route, the route should use
  only user information specific to the
- currently logged in user. More specifically, if there was a
  `"/customers/me/addresses"` route, the service method
- invoked could have a signature of `"getAddresses($customerId)"`, but in
  the `webapi.xml`, the $customerId parameter
- **would be forced to be the customer id of the current authenticated
  user.**
- **The forced override parameter configuration is in the webapi.**

---

```
   <data>
     <parameter name="customer.id" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
   </data>
```

and for business logic of this function is in file -

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamOverriderCustomerId.php

```
   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public function getOverriddenValue()
   {
       if ($this->userContext->getUserType() === UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER) {
           return $this->userContext->getUserId();
   }
   return null;
   }
```

**So this is how Magento get Customer Id between API calls !!**

---

**Another solution**

```
$ch = curl_init('dev.magento2.com/rest/V1/customers/me');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
echo $json->id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Please put below code of paramOverrider in your webapi definition where you need customer Id.

```
<data>
     <parameter name="customer.id" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note to the accepted answer, you need to also add the parameter to the service method in order to use it. So after adding the XML in the webapi.xml, using the name of the parameter add the same name for the variable in the method prototype.